# Already installed lsb_core not detected by OpenCl installer on Debian 9

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, opencl, libraries, lsb

I'm trying to install an OpenCL runtime on my Debian 9 virtual machine (on GCP) and I get an error of missing libraries when checking the requirements.
Particularly, it says lsb_core is not install, but when I try apt-get install lsb_core it says it's already installed and updated.
Is there something I'm missing? I can't find information about configuring something else in order for OpenCL to detect lsb_core.

Comment: please share the error text

Comment: Could you please share the full error message? Also, if you also are following any documentation, would also be helpful if you could provide it.